# Old HD not botting, now external drive, can't get files

Tags: boot, external-hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery, hard-drive-failure

SO my old hard drive wouldn't boot anymore, I think the error had something to do with MUI not being full or something? So I bought a new computer and pulled the drive from my old computer and put it into an enclosure. It is registering on my new computer as I:, but I get an error I:/ is not accessible The request could not be performed because of an I/O Device Error.

I am guessing I need to put a master boot record on the external drive to get it to be recognized? I have a ton of pics on that drive, most are backed up, but I got a few months behind and CHristmas and a few other important months of pics are on there and I don't want to lose them (or pay $3000 to recover them either). Any ideas?

Comment: What is *"MUI"*?  Do any of your PCs have in their BIOS program the capability to run the SMART tests?  I have an HP that can run quick, short and extended (reads every sector) tests on an HDD.

Answer (score 0):

Create a bootable usb that gives you an ntfs platform to work from.
[Hirens is the easy answer.](http://www.rmprepusb.com/tutorials/hbcd) Beware playing around with included software you are not familiar with.

Once you are running mini-xp from the hirens launcher menu select disk image from the backup menu and image the disk to another disk. Try to copy only data filled areas but since the partition table is screwed this might prove difficult.
After you make an image I recommend Disk Genius, Smart Partition Recovery, or PartitionRecovery from hirens recovery menu.
Any of these should be able to repair your partition.

Whatever you do make the image before attempting to recover anything